# How to print hash values with pipe separated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have an hash array as shown below:

```
sample = {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>{:c1=>abc, :c2=>xyz}, :d=>3}
```

And my desired output is:

```
1|2|abc|xyz|3
```

But if I use the command: `sample.values.join("|")`

My output is getting displayed as below:

```
1|2|c1abcc2xyz|3
```

Please help me out with this query. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

```
sample.values.flat_map { |x| x.is_a?(Hash) ? x.values : [x] }.join("|")
#=> "1|2|abc|xyz|3"
```

Comment: same code like mine,but in brief. Thus you got marks but I didn't :(

Comment: @RubyLovely: I didn't see yours, but well, usually the more functional approach you take, the more compact and clear the code :-) If I may say, it's better not to use `next` in blocks, use conditionals as expressions whenever possible. And somehow the fact that map+flatten(1)=flat_map (known as concat in many functional language) is not widely known yet.

Answer (score 4):

To handle arbitrary depth, you need to use recursion, like this:

```
def nested_values(object)
  object.values.reduce([]) do |array, value|
    array + (value.is_a?(Hash) ? nested_values(value) : [value])
  end
end

sample = {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>{:c1=>:abc, :c2=>:xyz}, :d=>3}
p nested_values(sample).join("|")
```

Output:

```
"1|2|abc|xyz|3"
```

Comment: Note that you manually implemented the abstraction `flat_map` with a `reduce` (not also that using `+` to concatenate arrays is a heavy operation).

Comment: @tokland, ah yes, forgot about `flat_map`, +1 to your answer :)

Comment: man, that's fair play, +1 for using a recursive flattener ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this quite tricky simple code. it will return what u expected

```
 sample = {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>{:c1=>abc, :c2=>xyz}, :d=>3}

  b= []

 sample.values.each do |a|

 if a.class != Hash

  b << a

 else

  c =a.values

  b << c

 end

 end

 b.join('|')

 => "1|2|abc|xyz|3"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sample = {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>{:c1=>:abc, :c2=>:xyz}, :d=>3}
sample.values.map{|i| next i.values if i.instance_of? Hash ; i}.flatten.join('|')
#=> "1|2|abc|xyz|3"
```